how to override a google auth screen with a custom template
I want a custom template in the url http://accounts/google/login. How do I do it.I just want some stying in it with CSS.  Suggest a stepwise solution.Should I try custom template but where do i place it and what to name it. I want to remove the menu div.
I have no idea what to do. so i tried nothing

can you refer to the package that you are currently using ? is it djoser ?

https://github.com/Aalok48/Gmail-Registration.git
Here is the github link. Can you please check it and tell how to override the defualt template that is being rendered in the http://localhost:8000/accounts/google/login/
url and change it without loosing the functionality of the login with google button?

it can be seen (from installed apps in your settings) that you are using djangosocialaccount library.
you can use your own template file and URL to provide custom template and still manage to get the same result as the provided example from the package.
  {% load socialaccount %}
<!--- your html normal form here -->

<a href="{% provider_login_url "openid" openid="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id" next="/success/url/" %}">Google</a>
<a href="{% provider_login_url "twitter" %}">Twitter</a>

for more detail please refer to the package documents
